# How to trace tree diagram in tcl

Tags: canvas, tree, tcl

I am looking for a good way to draw a tree diagram (vertical) like [this](http://www.syque.com/quality_tools/toolbook/Tree/vary.htm)

I currently use a canvas widget , what do you think ? , Are there any other widget to make it easier

Comment: A canvas is not a terrible solution — menubuttons would be a terrible solution! — though it doesn't automate layout. That linked page points to things that could be solved in several ways though; you should be much more specific…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at graphviz (it is a graph visualization software) and tcldot (its tcl bindings)...

http://www.graphviz.org/

http://wiki.tcl.tk/8634

Comment: Would be better if a worked example was included here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the limit of tcldot. I prefered the treectrl because this has more documentation.

I adapt my treectrl to have a diagram